# SSH Session Capture

Tags: c#, java, session, ssh

I need to capture and monitor the ssh session through Java or C#.
Just like Fiddler for Http.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you want the content of the ssh session? (like what they type or what files they send?) or the ssh protocol level exchanges? Either way, you cannot snoop on the ssh traffic without knowledge of the keys involved. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want some methods like BeforeRequest,BeforeResponse etc.
I have access of keys.

Answer (score 2):

You want to see the *inside* of an SSH session from the outside? Do you have access the the keys involved? If not, you won't be able to do it.

Comment: I have keys access. And I want some functions like beforeRequest , beforeResponse etc

Comment: what do you consider a request to be? a keystroke? a file transfer? a channel openning?

Comment: It can be anything , but for now file transfer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).
Wrieshark uses libpcap/WinPcap  unter the hood in case you need an API.
Look through the [link list](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/links.htm) for various APIs in .NET and Java.

Comment: you will see all encrypted traffic in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SSHLog: https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

It's a daemon that monitors SSH logins as well as user activity. All user activity (everything that happens on the shell) is passively recorded and available to inspect.  It supports piping to log files, statsd, Slack, and a few other things out of the box.

It has a plug-in architecture which natively uses Python, but you could bind your Java or C# code to it fairly easily.